# Read records from CSV file and print report

Tags: python-3.x

I have been working on a program for a week now, but have been unable to get it to work according to the guidelines.

In this program (**payroll.py**), I have to open the CSV data file (**employees.csv**), read the records in the file, and produce a payroll report using the functions in payroll.py. The output should be **printed**, *not* written to a separate output file, and should end up looking like this:

```
LastName    FirstName    Hours    RegHours    OTHours    RegPay    OTPay    GrossPay    Deductions    NetPay
Hightower   Michael      42.0     40.0        2.0        400.00    30.00    430.00      107.07        322.93
Jackson     Samuel       53.0     40.0        13.0       506.00    246.68   752.67      187.42        565.25
Jones       Catherine    35.0     35.0        0.00       680.05    0.00     680.05      169.33        510.72
```

The payroll program works just fine on its own (without calling the CSV file), but when I try to call the file (using "**from csv import reader**"), one of two things happens:

1) I can call the first three columns (last name, first name, and hours), but I am unable to "insert" the additional columns (I get an index error because, of course, those columns don't exist in the original CSV file), or

2) The program only pulls up one entire record, which happens to be the last record in the CSV file.

Any guidance on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the code for **payroll.py**:

```
def main() :
    employeeFirstName, employeeLastName = employeeFullName()
    employeePayRate, employeeHoursWorked = employeePay()
    employeeRegularHours, employeeOvertimeHours = calculateRegularHours(employeeHoursWorked)
    employeeOvertimeHours = calculateOvertimeHours(employeeHoursWorked)
    employeeTotalHours = calculateTotalHours(employeeRegularHours, employeeOvertimeHours)
    regularPayAmount = calculateRegularPay(employeePayRate, employeeRegularHours)
    overtimePayAmount = calculateOvertimePay(employeePayRate, employeeOvertimeHours)
    grossPayAmount = calculateGrossPay(regularPayAmount, overtimePayAmount)
    federalTaxWithheld = calculateFederalTax(grossPayAmount)
    stateTaxWithheld = calculateStateTax(grossPayAmount)
    medicareTaxWithheld = calculateMedicareTax(grossPayAmount)
    socSecTaxWithheld = calculateSocSecTax(grossPayAmount)
    totalTaxesWithheld = calculateTotalTaxes(federalTaxWithheld, stateTaxWithheld, medicareTaxWithheld, socSecTaxWithheld)
    netPayAmount = calculateNetPay(grossPayAmount, totalTaxesWithheld)
    payrollSummaryReport(employeeFirstName, employeeLastName, employeePayRate, employeeRegularHours, employeeOvertimeHours, employeeTotalHours, regularPayAmount, overtimePayAmount, grossPayAmount, federalTaxWithheld, stateTaxWithheld, medicareTaxWithheld, socSecTaxWithheld, totalTaxesWithheld, netPayAmount)

def employeeFullName() :
    employeeFirstName = str(input("Enter the employee's first name: "))
    employeeLastName = str(input("Enter the employee's last name: "))
    return employeeFirstName, employeeLastName

def employeePay() :
    employeePayRate = float(input("Enter the employee's hourly pay rate: "))
    employeeHoursWorked = float(input("Enter the employee's hours worked: "))
    return employeePayRate, employeeHoursWorked

def calculateRegularHours(employeeHoursWorked) :
    if employeeHoursWorked < 40 :
        employeeRegularHours = employeeHoursWorked
        employeeOvertimeHours = 0

    else:
        employeeRegularHours = 40
        employeeOvertimeHours = employeeHoursWorked - 40

    return employeeRegularHours, employeeOvertimeHours

def calculateOvertimeHours(employeeHoursWorked) :
    if employeeHoursWorked > 40 :
        employeeOvertimeHours = employeeHoursWorked - 40

    else :
        employeeOvertimeHours = 0

    return employeeOvertimeHours

def calculateTotalHours(employeeRegularHours, employeeOvertimeHours) :
    employeeTotalHours = employeeRegularHours + employeeOvertimeHours
    return employeeTotalHours

def calculateRegularPay(employeePayRate, employeeHoursWorked) :
    regularPayAmount = employeePayRate * employeeHoursWorked
    return regularPayAmount

def calculateOvertimePay(employeePayRate, employeeOvertimeHours) :
    overtimePayRate = 1.5
    overtimePayAmount = (employeePayRate * employeeOvertimeHours) * overtimePayRate
    return overtimePayAmount

def calculateGrossPay(regularPayAmount, overtimePayAmount) :
    grossPayAmount = regularPayAmount + overtimePayAmount
    return grossPayAmount

def calculateFederalTax(grossPayAmount) :
    federalTaxRate = 0.124
    federalTaxWithheld = grossPayAmount * federalTaxRate
    return federalTaxWithheld

def calculateStateTax(grossPayAmount) :
    stateTaxRate = 0.049
    stateTaxWithheld = grossPayAmount * stateTaxRate
    return stateTaxWithheld

def calculateMedicareTax(grossPayAmount) :
    medicareTaxRate = 0.014
    medicareTaxWithheld = grossPayAmount * medicareTaxRate
    return medicareTaxWithheld

def calculateSocSecTax(grossPayAmount) :
    socSecTaxRate = 0.062
    socSecTaxWithheld = grossPayAmount * socSecTaxRate
    return socSecTaxWithheld

def calculateTotalTaxes(federalTaxWithheld, stateTaxWithheld, medicareTaxWithheld, socSecTaxWithheld) :
    totalTaxesWithheld = federalTaxWithheld + stateTaxWithheld + medicareTaxWithheld + socSecTaxWithheld
    return totalTaxesWithheld

def calculateNetPay(grossPayAmount, totalTaxesWithheld) :
    netPayAmount = grossPayAmount - totalTaxesWithheld
    return netPayAmount

def payrollSummaryReport(employeeFirstName, employeeLastName, employeePayRate, employeeRegularHours, employeeOvertimeHours, employeeTotalHours, regularPayAmount, overtimePayAmount, grossPayAmount, federalTaxWithheld, stateTaxWithheld, medicareTaxWithheld, socSecTaxWithheld, totalTaxesWithheld, netPayAmount) :
    print()
    print("\t\t\t\t\t\tPayroll Summary Report")
    print()
    print("%-12s%-12s%-8s%-10s%-10s%-12s%-10s%-11s%-13s%-10s" % ("LastName", "FirstName", "Hours", "RegHours", "OTHours", "RegPay", "OTPay", "GrossPay", "Deductions", "NetPay"))
    print("%-12s%-12s%-8.2f%-10.2f%-10.2f$%-11.2f$%-9.2f$%-10.2f$%-12.2f$%-10.2f" % (employeeLastName, employeeFirstName, employeeTotalHours, employeeRegularHours, employeeOvertimeHours, regularPayAmount, overtimePayAmount, grossPayAmount, totalTaxesWithheld, netPayAmount))

main ()
```

The CSV file (**employees.csv**) I need to use looks like this:

```
First,Last,Hours,Pay
Matthew,Hightower,42,10
Samuel,Jackson,53,12.65
Catherine,Jones,35,19.43
Charlton,Heston,52,10
Karen,Black,40,12
Sid,Caesar,38,15
George,Kennedy,25,35
Linda,Blair,42,18.6
Beverly,Garland,63,10
Jerry,Stiller,52,15
Efrem,Zimbalist,34,16
Linda,Harrison,24,14
Erik,Estrada,41,15.5
Myrna,Loy,40,14.23
```

Comment: just to clarify what I need to figure out:

Comment: a loop that opens the CSV file (employees.csv) and reads each employee/line, performs the calculations from the payroll functions (from payroll.py), and then prints out the results in a "table" format (as shown in my original post).

Answer (score 0):

You can treat your `.csv` file as a regular one. No need for `reader`. Here is a function that might deal with your file:

```
 def get_data(fname):
  ''' 
    Function returns the dictionary with following 
    format:
    { 0 : {
        "fname": "...",
        "lname": "...",
        "gross": "...",
      },
      1 : {
        ....,
        ,,,,
      },
    }
  '''
  result = {} # return value 
  i = 0 # you can zip range() if you want to
  with open(fname, 'r') as f: 
    for line in f.readlines()[1:]:
      result[i] = {}
      tmp = line.split(",") # list of values from file 
      # access file values by their index, e.g. 
      # tmp[0] -> first name
      # tmp[1] -> last name
      # tmp[2] -> hours
      # tmp[3] -> pay rate

      # do calculations using your functions (calculateOvertimePay,
      # calculateTotalHours, etc.) and store the results in dictionary
      # e.g: 
      result[i]["fname"] = tmp[0]
      result[i]["lname"] = tmp[1]
      # ...
      # do calculations for report
      # ...
      # result[i]["regular"] = calc...(....)
      # result[i]["overtime"] = calc...(....)
      result[i]["gross"] = calculateGrossPay(result[i]["regular"], result[i]["overtime"])
      i += 1
    return result
```

There are several thing your might want to do with your `payrollSummaryReport(...)` function to improve it:

- replace your huge argument list with `dict`, or `list`
- tinker it a bit to fit your requirements

Your might do your improvements in this way:

```
def payrollSummaryReport(vals) :
    print()
    print("\t\t\t\t\t\tPayroll Summary Report")
    print()
    print("%-12s%-12s%-8s%-10s%-10s%-12s%-10s%-11s%-13s%-10s" %\
     ("LastName", "FirstName", "Hours", "RegHours", "OTHours", "RegPay", "OTPay", "GrossPay", "Deductions", "NetPay"))
    for i in vals:
      print("%-12s%-12s%-8.2f%-10.2f%-10.2f$%-11.2f$%-9.2f$%-10.2f$%-12.2f$%-10.2f" %\
       (vals[i]["fname"], vals[i]["lname"], vals[i]["gross"], ''' repeat for all fields '''))
```