# Where is this extra line come from when printing an item from a set? (CSV) file Using Python and Spyder4

Tags: python, csv

I am confounded by my print(tmp[3]) function of a item, in a set. When the item tmp[3] is printed it gives me two lines one with the value and the other empty. Everything runs well up to line 132.

The goal of the program is to print a The payroll summary report is based on information from previous programs (with different rates). You should use individual functions to perform the following:

Compute the regular hours worked (40 hours and below)
Compute the overtime hours worked (those above 40 hours)
Compute the regular pay (regular hours times regular pay)
Compute the overtime pay (overtime hours times regular pay times 1.5)
Compute the gross pay
Compute the amount of federal tax withheld (15.1% of gross pay)
Compute the amount of state tax withheld (5.5% of gross pay)
Compute the amount of medicare withheld (1.2% of gross pay)
Compute the amount of social security withheld (4.8% of gross pay)
Compute the total deductions (federal tax + state tax + medicare + social security)
Compute the net pay (gross pay - deductions)
Compute the total (total for everyone) net pay
Print (to the screen) a clean summary report (see the output above)
Print (to the screen) the total net pay.

I found the functions for an input based version so it was a challenge for me to extract data from a csv and use it in the functions.

IF you want an easier copy and past program similar to this one here is the link:[Read records from CSV file and print report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50216887/python-read-records-from-csv-file-and-print-report)

The expected result of print(tmp[3]) is "10". Actual result.. "10
                                                                                           ". 
I don't know why it prints an extra line. THe symptom of this problem i thinkis not being able to calculate the regular pay = Payrate * hoursWorked. The expect output is 420. 42(payrate) * 10(hours) = 420
Here is the error at line 133  "TypeError:can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" at line 132
This is a homework assignment and I'm just looking to solve this error, so putting my whole program seems unnecessary.

Here is the csv file:

```
First, Last, Hours, Pay
Matthew, Hightower, 42, 10
Samuel, Jackson, 53, 12.58
Catherine, Jones, 35, 19.43
```

THis is the whole program.
def main():

```
results = get_data("employeestest.csv")

payrollSummaryReport(results)

def get_data(fname):

Function returns the dictionary with following 
format:
{ 0 : {
    "fname": "...",
    "lname": "...",
    "gross": "...",
  },
  1 : {
    ....,
    ,,,,
  },
}
```

result = {} # return value 
  i = 0 # you can zip range() if you want to
  with open(fname, 'r') as f:

```
  for line in f.readlines()[1:]:

      result[i] = {}
      tmp = line.split(",") # list of values from file 
      # access file values by their index, e.g. 
      # tmp[0] -> first name
      # tmp[1] -> last name
      # tmp[2] -> hours
      # tmp[3] -> pay rate
      employeeRegularHours, employeeOvertimeHours = calculateRegularHours(tmp[2])
      employeeOvertimeHours = calculateOvertimeHours(tmp[2])
      employeeTotalHours = calculateTotalHours(employeeRegularHours, employeeOvertimeHours)
      print(tmp[3])
This is were I print the item but it comes out to 
"10
       "
 I don't know why it skips a line. I found this error through this "TypeError:can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" at line 132

      #print(employeeRegularHours)
      regularPayAmount = calculateRegularPay(tmp[3], employeeRegularHours)
      overtimePayAmount = calculateOvertimePay(tmp[3], employeeOvertimeHours)
      grossPayAmount = calculateGrossPay(regularPayAmount, overtimePayAmount)
      federalTaxWithheld = calculateFederalTax(grossPayAmount)
      stateTaxWithheld = calculateStateTax(grossPayAmount)
      medicareTaxWithheld = calculateMedicareTax(grossPayAmount)
      socSecTaxWithheld = calculateSocSecTax(grossPayAmount)
      totalTaxesWithheld = calculateTotalTaxes(federalTaxWithheld, stateTaxWithheld, 
      medicareTaxWithheld, socSecTaxWithheld)
      netPayAmount = calculateNetPay(grossPayAmount, totalTaxesWithheld)
      #(calculateOvertimePay, calculateTotalHours) = 
      #etc.) and store the results in dictionary
      # e.g: 

      result[i]["fname"] = tmp[0]
      result[i]["lname"] = tmp[1]
      result[i]["hours"] = tmp[2]
      result[i]["payrate"] = tmp[3]
  # ...
      # do calculations for report
      # ...
      result[i]["regular"] = employeeRegularHours
      result[i]["overtime"] = employeeOvertimeHours
      result[i]["totalhours"] = employeeTotalHours
      result[i]["regPay"] = regularPayAmount
      result[i]["overPay"] = overtimePayAmount
      result[i]["gross"] = grossPayAmount
      result[i]["fedtax"] = federalTaxWithheld
      result[i]["stateTax"] = stateTaxWithheld
      result[i]["medTax"] = medicareTaxWithheld
      result[i]["socsectax"] = socSecTaxWithheld
      result[i]["totaltax"] = totalTaxesWithheld
      result[i]["netpay"] = netPayAmount
      i += 1
  return result

def calculateRegularHours(employeeHoursWorked) :
   #print(employeeHoursWorked)

   if float(employeeHoursWorked)  < 40.0 :
      employeeRegularHours = employeeHoursWorked
      employeeOvertimeHours = 0.0
   else:

     employeeRegularHours = 40.0
     employeeOvertimeHours = 0.0
    #employeeOvertimeHours = employeeHoursWorked - 40.0


   return employeeRegularHours, employeeOvertimeHours

def calculateOvertimeHours(employeeHoursWorked) :
   if float(employeeHoursWorked) > 40 :
       #float(employeeOvertimeHours) = employeeHoursWorked - 40
       #print(employeeHoursWorked)
       employeeOvertimeHours = 0.0
   else :
       employeeOvertimeHours = 0

   return employeeOvertimeHours

def calculateTotalHours(employeeRegularHours, employeeOvertimeHours) :
    employeeTotalHours = employeeRegularHours #+ employeeOvertimeHours
    return employeeTotalHours


def calculateRegularPay(employeePayRate, employeeHoursWorked) :

    regularPayAmount = employeePayRate * employeeHoursWorked
    return regularPayAmount

def calculateOvertimePay(employeePayRate, employeeOvertimeHours) :
    overtimePayRate = 1.5
    overtimePayAmount = (employeePayRate * employeeOvertimeHours) * 
    overtimePayRate
    return overtimePayAmount

def calculateGrossPay(regularPayAmount, overtimePayAmount) :
    grossPayAmount = regularPayAmount + overtimePayAmount
    return grossPayAmount

def calculateFederalTax(grossPayAmount) :
    federalTaxRate = 0.151
    federalTaxWithheld = grossPayAmount * federalTaxRate
    return federalTaxWithheld

def calculateStateTax(grossPayAmount) :
    stateTaxRate = 0.055
    stateTaxWithheld = grossPayAmount * stateTaxRate
    return stateTaxWithheld

def calculateMedicareTax(grossPayAmount) :
    medicareTaxRate = 0.012
    medicareTaxWithheld = grossPayAmount * medicareTaxRate
    return medicareTaxWithheld

def calculateSocSecTax(grossPayAmount) :
    socSecTaxRate = 0.048
    socSecTaxWithheld = grossPayAmount * socSecTaxRate
    return socSecTaxWithheld

def calculateTotalTaxes(federalTaxWithheld, stateTaxWithheld,         
    medicareTaxWithheld, socSecTaxWithheld) :
    totalTaxesWithheld = federalTaxWithheld + stateTaxWithheld +     
    medicareTaxWithheld + socSecTaxWithheld
    return totalTaxesWithheld

def calculateNetPay(grossPayAmount, totalTaxesWithheld) :
    netPayAmount = grossPayAmount - totalTaxesWithheld
    return netPayAmount

def payrollSummaryReport(vals):
    print()
    print("\t\t\t\t\t\tPayroll Summary Report")
    print("%-12s%-12s%-8s%-10s%-10s%-12s%-10s%-11s%-13s%-10s" %\
     ("LastName", "FirstName", "Hours", "RegHours", "OTHours", "RegPay", "OTPay", "GrossPay", "Deductions", "NetPay"))
    for i in vals:
       print("%-12s%-12s%-8.2f%-10.2f%-10.2f$%-11.2f$%-9.2f$%-10.2f$%-12.2f$%-10.2f" %\   

       (vals[i]["fname"], vals[i]["lname"], vals[i]["gross"]))
```

main()

```
                     [Expected Output][1]   

   Payroll Summary Report
```

Last Name   First Name  Hours   Regular Hours       Overtime Hours
Hightower   Matthew        42.0             40.0          2.0                           400.0                30.0         430.00              107.07             322.93
Jackson         Samuel             53.0             40.0                                  13.0                           506.0             246.68      752.67              187.42            565.25
Jones             Catherine        35.0             35.0                                    0.0                           680.05               0.0           680.05             169.33             510.72

Total Net Pay                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         1,398.90

Regular Pay    OT Pay     Gross Pay     Deductions      Net Pay

Comment: There needs to be enough code (and data) in your question to reproduce the problem. aka [mre]. You should also add the desired output to the question, not down here in a comment.

Comment: be please more specific

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that changing it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `f.readlines` includes end of line (EOL) characters, so if you split the line on commas and print the last item it will print the value *and* the end of line character(s).  If you do `print(repr(tmp[3]))` you will see something like `'10\n'`.

You can strip the EOL from the line like this:

```
tmp = line.strip().split(",")
```

However, since you are processing a csv file you can use Python's built in [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module, which will handle some of the details for you

```
import csv

# Do stuff

with open(fname, 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # Skip header row
    next(reader)

    # reader yield lists, but since we know each list will have
    # the same number of elements we can unpack them into
    # four separate variables - this is more readable than 
    # referencing by index.
    for first_name, last_name, hours, pay_rate in reader:

        employeeRegularHours, employeeOvertimeHours = calculateRegularHours(hours)
        employeeOvertimeHours = calculateOvertimeHours(hours)
        employeeTotalHours = calculateTotalHours(employeeRegularHours, employeeOvertimeHours)

        # Do more stuff
```

Note that `hours` and `pay_rate` are *strings* when read from the file.  If you want to use them as numbers you will need to convert them using [int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) or [float](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float), depending on what kind of numbers you want.

Comment: Finally the variable names are can be used by line 132. I thank you for the help. Now I just must put the results from the calculations into the payrollSummaryReport function..